# Chart to multiply data series without date data

Tags: javascript

I tried to customize a `highstock` chart for data series without date [data](http://joxi.ru/L21W0kPC83qRJr).

```
series: [{ name: "nameA", data: [value1, value2, ... valueN]}, {...}]
```

Is there a way to build `highstock` chart like [this](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare) without date data (only for value) with enabled `rangeSelector.selected` settings.
Also, I need to have [buttons](http://joxi.ru/12MeDwqtMWG0y2) for different ranges with no date values.

Comment: why are you not using chart.js? very easy to use.

Comment: I need to have a range selector(timeline below chart)

Comment: check this [line chart](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html)

Comment: you can find all demos [here](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/)

Comment: no, I need that http://joxi.ru/Vm6aQNPHD6qKlr

Comment: sorry, it is a navigator(not a timeline)

Comment: I find a good example (combining some d3 libraries)
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172 https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172/
but it is not the simplest, I think.

Comment: I can help you out in chart js library if you want to use any.

Comment: I don't understand what your suggestion is. You wanna say that I need to build 2 chartJs-charts and make communications between them?

Comment: My suggestion is that choose any sample from chartjs library that fullfill your requirements and i can you help out in that if you had any problems.

Comment: ok, I get it, thanks for the help.

Comment: You can also look into this library [jqwidgets chart](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/index.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer on my question from comments is provided by ppotaczek:

> navigator and rangeSelector based on time, so you have two options. You can use milliseconds as a basic numeric time value or create your own rangeSelecgor and change navigator axis type in Highcharts core: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f5wum6np)

I chose a variant with ms, and set next options:

```
rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [{
      type: 'millisecond',
      count: 10,
      text: '10'
    },{
      type: 'millisecond',
      count: 50,
      text: '50'
    },{
      type: 'all',
      text: 'All'
    }]
  },
...
navigator: {
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        formatter: function () {
          return this.value;
        }
      }
    }
  },
...
xAxis: {
    labels: {
      format: '{value}'
    },
  },
...
series: [{data: [[0, value0], [1, value1]], ... [n, valueN]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `highstock.js` source code and `chart` constructor, you will be able to create basic chart with highstock features:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    }],
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: true,
        inputDateFormat: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
        inputEditDateFormat: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
        // Custom parser to parse the %H:%M:%S.%L format
        inputDateParser: function(value) {
            value = value.split(/[:\.]/);
            return Date.UTC(
                1970,
                0,
                1,
                parseInt(value[0], 10),
                parseInt(value[1], 10),
                parseInt(value[2], 10),
                parseInt(value[3], 10)
            );
        }
    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: true
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h1yudspa/

Comment: yes, I do the same, and if you look at [top zoom buttons](http://joxi.ru/RmzYq74u03a7jr) and [navigation](http://joxi.ru/Vm6aQNPHD6MQWr) of your example, you will see that the components work with dateFormat data(for example in zoom buttons we can't set buttons for integer xAxis value, that we have in the example, and on navigation panel we see values in range in dataFormat ). The question is there is a way to work with dataType: integer(or other types of numbers), in purpose to get correct work zoom buttons and navigation panel. Or maybe available some kind of settings to fix the problems.

Comment: Hi Maxim Novikov, `navigator` and `rangeSelector` based on time, so you have two options. You can use milliseconds as a basic numeric time value or create your own `rangeSelecgor` and change navigator axis type in Highcharts core: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f5wum6np/